# python request param

Tags: python, django

I m working on django view.I m posting a form which has a param name 'service'.Service is checkbox so it will have mulitple values.When i am getting the values of service in my code it is giving me only one value not the array.Here is my sample code

```
 {% for ser in allService %}
 <td  >         
     <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="{{ ser.id }}" >{{ ser.description }}
 </td>
 {% endfor %}

def update(request):
     service=request.POST.get('service')
     print service
```

how can i get a array.In java we getParameterValues('service')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`POST` attribute is a `QueryDict`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), so you can do this:

```
service = request.POST.getlist('service')
```

Comment: A
thanks for the answer.Can you give me link for this documentation